# IF with a misbehaving INSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column containing a series of strings, including numbers as strings (and before one of you suggests it, the type ain't changing)

```
TableA:
ColA
-----
''
(NULL)
'5 Yippee'
'6 Yeps'
'7'
'8 Awesome'
```

I am trying to output based on the number. Originally, it was assumed that all numbers in this column would be followed by a space. As it turns out, they aren't.

So far I have

```
FOR x in 
(SELECT * FROM FUNCTION_THAT_OUTPUTS_COLA(var1,var2)) -- ColA, not Cola
LOOP
IF ColA is not null
    IF instr(x.ColA,' ') >0 -- There's a space in here
    THEN
      v_output.Col:= SUBSTR(x.ColA,1,INSTR(x.ColA,' '));
      PIPE ROW(v_output);
    ELSE
      v_output:= x.ColA;
      PIPE ROW(v_ouptut);
    END IF;
END IF;
```

Unfortunately, while it strips the null, it also strips the '7'

The ideal output here is:

```
'5'
'6'
'7'
'8'
```

Can anyone help me out here, my mind is totally blank?

Edit:

Found it, it was a typo that was fixed when I transposed it here

Thanks guys

Comment: Edit your question and provide your desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edits made

Comment: It would help if you posted code that compiled, and was complete - include the type declarations, a complete function this snippet is from (doesn't matter if the value actually come from a table or collection, it just has to demonstrate your problem), and that you can run standalone. Trying to patch up the mistakes and typos, this does seem to do what you want, which makes it kind of hard to tell you what's wrong. Can you also clarify if your values include the single quotes, and if `(NULL)` means the value is actually null?

Comment: @AlexPoole - the code won't do what the OP wants, because he is searching for a space in the input string to indicate the end of the leading "number". When the whole string is just the number, there will be no space, so the INSTR returns 0 and the SUBSTR returns null.

Comment: @mathguy - but then it goes into the `else` and doesn't do the `substr` at all? It seemes to work with the sample data, anyway. Still, better ways to do it...

Comment: @AlexPoole - you are right. I should read the whole code more closely! He is already doing what I suggested in my Answer (which I will delete).

Answer (score 3):

How about using regular expression ([regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm))

```
select result from (
    select regexp_substr(ColA, '[0-9]+',1,1) as result from tableA
) where result is not null
```

**output**:

`5
 6
 7
 8`

Comment: This is the right idea.  I think `'^[0-9]+'` might be more appropriate, but that is a quibble (whether the numbers have to start at the beginning of the string).

Comment: @GordonLinoff It wasn't specified whether the numbers are at the beginning or not - that's why I didn't put `^`. However, if they are, then you are right..